# Which one is correct "me" or "I am"?

Tags: pronouns, objects

In this [blog](https://dotseng.wordpress.com/2012/04/), I think objective form of pronoun "me" is wrong.

> As always, I give you ONLY the facts. You decide for yourself whether he is right or **me**.

Can I rephrase the sentence as follows?

> As always, I give you ONLY the facts. You decide for yourself whether he is right or **I am**.

Comment: Whether he is right or I am (right). ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, "me" is incorrect there. Your revision using "I am" is correct.

"me" is the the objective case of "I". You use it when you're the object: "He gave it to me."

---

As we're talking about "I" and "me" I'll point out an error people frequently make, including native speakers: It's "me" even if you're not alone in the sentence. You'll commonly see "He gave James and I a lift" (even from native speakers) but it should be "He gave James and me a lift". The rule is simple: If you removed "James and", would you use "I" or "me"? Are you the *subject* (I) or the *object* (me)?